# VS 2015 cannot open .coveragexml generated by CodeCoverage.exe

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, code-coverage, mstest, vstest

I am following [Code Coverage Results Import (C#, VB.NET)](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389770#CodeCoverageResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-VisualStudioCodeCoverage) documentation for SonarQube.

For my project, I am able to generate test coverage binary file as "**SonarQubeTests.csproj.coverage**"

Visual Studio can open this file with no problem. I can see all the details.

Then when I try to generate ".coveragexml" file with following command;

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools\CodeCoverage.exe" "analyze /output:C:\SonarQubeTests.csproj.coveragexml C:\SonarQubeTests.csproj.coverage"
```

It does generate ".coveragexml" file, but when I try to open Visual Studio it gives me following error:

[image]

I can open this file with text editor and content seems all fine. But neither Visual Studio 2015 nor sonarqube does not read this file.

What I am missing here?

P.S I have also runner settings for Ms Test runner as below.
Not sure if this will effect something;

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RunSettings>  
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->  
  <RunConfiguration>  
    <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>  
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->  
    <ResultsDirectory>C:\</ResultsDirectory>  

    <!-- [x86] | x64    
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->  
    <TargetPlatform>x86</TargetPlatform>  

    <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->  
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework45</TargetFrameworkVersion>  

    <!-- Path to Test Adapters -->  
    <TestAdaptersPaths>%SystemDrive%\Temp\foo;%SystemDrive%\Temp\bar</TestAdaptersPaths>  
  </RunConfiguration>  

  <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->  
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>  
    <DataCollectors>  
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">  
        <Configuration>  
          <CodeCoverage>  
            <ModulePaths>  
              <Exclude>  
                <ModulePath>.*CPPUnitTestFramework.*</ModulePath>  
              </Exclude>  
            </ModulePaths>  

            <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->  
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>  
            <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>  
            <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>  
            <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>  

          </CodeCoverage>  
        </Configuration>  
      </DataCollector>  

    </DataCollectors>  
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>  

  <!-- Parameters used by tests at runtime -->  
  <TestRunParameters>  
    <Parameter name="webAppUrl" value="http://localhost" />  
    <Parameter name="webAppUserName" value="Admin" />  
    <Parameter name="webAppPassword" value="Password" />  
  </TestRunParameters>  

  <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->  

  <!-- MSTest adapter -->  
  <MSTest>  
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>  
    <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>  
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>  
    <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>  
    <AssemblyResolution>  
      <Directory Path="D:\myfolder\bin\" includeSubDirectories="false"/>  
    </AssemblyResolution>  
  </MSTest>  

</RunSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use vstest.console to get code coverage directly. We do not sure whether VS could open the code coverage that generated by third party tools. 
I think if we could vstest.console to get the code coverage will has not problems. please try it to see the results.

Comment: CodeCoverage.exe is not third party. I am using it to generate .coveragexml. I am already using vstest.console.exe to generate .covagare file.

Comment: then you could drag .coverage file to VS directly and export it in coveragexml file

Comment: please read question carefully. I do not want manual process, this is a step for  SonarQube process, where I am trying to follow documentation.

Comment: if the file could not be opened with SonarQube peocess, I think this issue is related to SonarQube.